# Tensorflow documentation's example code on "Logging Device Placement" doesn't print out anything

Tags: tensorflow

[Tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/using_gpu/index.html) has the following example code on finding out the device placement of nodes. That is, on which device a particular computation takes place.

```
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
# Runs the op.
print sess.run(c)
```

For me, the code does not print out the locations of the devices like it is supposed to. I'm using the Jupyter notebook running on Ubuntu. How might I fix this or find out the information some other way?

Answer (score 12):

For Jupyter (and other) users, there is a recently-added feature that makes it possible to read back the device placement when you make a [`Session.run()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/client.html#Session.run) call and print it in your notebook.

```
# Creates a graph.
a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
c = tf.matmul(a, b)
# Creates a session with log_device_placement set to True.
sess = tf.Session()

# Runs the op.
options = tf.RunOptions(output_partition_graphs=True)
metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
c_val = sess.run(c, options=options, run_metadata=metadata)

print metadata.partition_graphs
```

The `metadata.partition_graphs` contains the actual nodes of the graph that executed, partitioned by device. The partitions aren't explicitly labeled with the device they represent, but every `NodeDef` in the graph has its `device` field set.

Comment: It just gave me: ``<google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedCompositeContainer object at 0x7f7ec6db1df8>``

Comment: just use `print metadata` instead of `print metadata.partition_graphs`. You'll see its a set of objects, you can view each by indices, like `print metadata.partition_graphs[0]`

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately Jupyter doesn't see the C++ error stdout messages that the device placement logging uses. There's a longer thread on the problem here:

https://github.com/nteract/hydrogen/issues/209

There's no easy workaround that I know of, other than running your script outside of Jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the device mapping printed to standard out of the jupyter notebook process in the terminal. It just doesn't get printed in the notebook.